# IOS self->isa deprecated but Object_setClass also gives a warning

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm busy with a library of a collegae. In his code he sets isa a few times. This stills works but is officially deprecated. The alternative should be the object_setClass function. But when I replace it I get a warning: *Implicit declaration of function 'object_setClass' is invalid in C99.*
Perhaps i am missing an import or something? Anyone an idea? Thanks.

```
if(nodePtr->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
{
    self->isa = [DDXMLElement class];
    //object_setClass(self, [DDXMLElement class]);
}
else if(nodePtr->type == XML_DOCUMENT_NODE)
{
    self->isa = [DDXMLDocument class];
    //object_setClass(self, [DDXMLDocument class]);
}
```

Comment: `#import <objc/runtime.h>`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's declared in `#include <objc/runtime.h>` -- have you included that header?

Comment: I tried something like that but i believe that was <runtime/runtime.h> which didn't exists. This solve the problem indeed. Thanks